# Spline Derivative

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, splines

I am using the spline toolbox to make a bicubic spline as follows:

```
ft = 'cubicinterp';
opts = fitoptions( ft );

[xInput, yInput, zOutput] = prepareSurfaceData( xMesh, yMesh, Z );
[fitresult, gof] = fit( [xInput, yInput], zOutput, ft, opts );
```

I know I can use http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/differentiate.html to differentiate with respect to either the x or y direction, but what I would like is to differentiate with respect to the values at the knots (i.e. Z).

Does this exist, or will I have to write my own?